# canread() function is always giving false

Tags: android, android-studio

```
val inputFile: File = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Ball - 113146.mp4")
// Check whether the input file exist or not
if (!inputFile.canRead()) {
throw FileNotFoundException("Unable to read $inputFile")
}
```

i'm expecting true from this canRead() function but it's always giving false. I have already taken the required permissions(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).`

Comment: There is more required then that permission. And that permission is useless for an Android 13 device. And you should also use file.exists().

Answer (score 0):

Your File does not exist.
Try to use `file.exists()` to check if the file exists or not.

Also, just the permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not enough if you are targeting Android Version 11.
This is because you are trying to get a file in the "Downloads" folder, so you need to use `Scoped Storage`.

More infos [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).